# Why Redis delete my datas after a couple of hours?

Tags: docker, redis

I am using Redis Image on Docker. After about 3 hours of launching container, I lost all my datas. How can I fix it? And why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

When saving data to redis you can set TTL (time to live) value. This is the number of seconds that indicate how long data will be valid.

Another possible issue could be that you didn't set up persistence volume for your Redis container. In this case, data is lost when the container restarts.